# Searching 2D array with numpy.where with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 2D array of arrays defined as follows:

```
traces = [['x1',11026,0,0,0,0],
          ['x0',11087,0,0,0,1],
          ['x0',11088,0,0,1,3],
          ['x0',11088,0,0,0,3],
          ['x0',11088,0,1,0,1]]
```

I want to find the index of the row which matches multiple conditions of selected columns. For example I want to find the row in this array where

```
row[0]=='x0' & row[1]==11088 & row[3]==1 & row[5]=1
```

Searching on this criteria should return 4.

I attempted to use numpy.where but can't seem to make it work with multiple conditions

```
print np.where((traces[:,0] == 'x0') & (traces[:,1] == 11088) & (traces[:,3] == 1) & (traces[:,5] == 1))
```

The above creates the warning

```
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison   print np.where((traces[:,0] == 'x0') & (traces[:,1] == 11088) & (traces[:,3]
== 1) & (traces[:,5] == 1)) (array([], dtype=int32),)
```

I've attempted to use `numpy.logical_and` as well and that doesn't seem to work either, creating similar warnings.

Any way I can do this using `numpy.where` without iterating over the whole 2D array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this comparison:

```
>>> traces[:,[0,1,3,5]] == ['x0', 11088, 1, 1]
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

we are looking for one (or more) row(s) with all values equal to True:

```
>>> np.where(np.all(traces[:,[0,1,3,5]] == ['x0', 11088, 1, 1], axis=1))
(array([4]),)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very elegant solution. What is the purpose of axis=1 here?

Comment: To sum along a specified axis, in this case to sum by row.

Comment: Better use [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) insteaf of `np.sum`, which is somewhat more elegant (and should perform better if that matters).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly assume you did something like this (conversion to `np.array`):

```
traces = [['x1',11026,0,0,0,0],
          ['x0',11087,0,0,0,1],
          ['x0',11088,0,0,1,3],
          ['x0',11088,0,0,0,3],
          ['x0',11088,0,1,0,1]]
          
traces = np.array(traces)
```

This exhibits the described error. The reason can be seen by printing the resulting array:

```
print(traces)
# array([['x1', '11026', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
#        ['x0', '11087', '0', '0', '0', '1'],
#        ['x0', '11088', '0', '0', '1', '3'],
#        ['x0', '11088', '0', '0', '0', '3'],
#        ['x0', '11088', '0', '1', '0', '1']],
#       dtype='<U5')
```

Numbers were converted to strings!

When constructing an array that contains values of different types, numpy usually creates an array of `dtype=object`. This works in most cases but has bad performance.

However, in this case numpy apparently tried to be smart and converted the data to a string type, which is more specific than object but general enough to take numbers - as strings.

As a solution construct the array explicitly as an "object array":

```
traces = np.array(traces, dtype='object')

print(np.where((traces[:,0] == 'x0') & (traces[:,1] == 11088) & (traces[:,3] == 1) & (traces[:,5] == 1)))
# (array([4], dtype=int32),)
```

Note that although this works, object arrays are often not a good idea to use. Consider instead to replace the strings in the first column with numeric values.

Comment: You are correct, it was cast into a numpy array and I didn't realize this would change the numbers to strings.

Comment: @ozal I was surprised by this too ;)